Running new drainpipe under a slab foundation
I am considering adding a bathroom to our single level slab foundation house (1940s era). I am trying to figure out how I'd add new drain pipe under the foundation. The bathroom would be positioned such that one of the walls would be an exterior one and the main sewer drain pipe is nearby in the yard, so is it possible to simply dig out the dirt on the outside wall and somehow cut a hole thru the foundation wall to run the pipe? Id then cut an access section the in slab top where the drains would go and hook up to the pipe that was run thru the wall.
If it is feasible, how would one cut the hole in the foundation wall? I'm sure I can't jack hammer as it would destroy the integrity of the foundation wall.
Here is a mockup:


First things first: find the existing pipe out in the yard where you want to attach to it, and also expose the bottom of your foundation footing. (I'm assuming you're correct that there is a true foundation wall extending below frost depth.) If the yard is not very level, or if there's a small difference between the two elevations, use a laser or water level to precisely determine the difference in elevation. This will help you determine whether it's possible for the new pipe to pass under the footing or whether it's necessary to penetrate the concrete wall.
If passing through the wall is the only way, or if you prefer it due to footing depth, a core drill is the right tool for the job. You'll need to determine what pipe size is required -- 3" is a maybe, 4" is for sure large enough. Actual outside diameter is 1/2" larger for those two sizes so you'll need a core drill at least 3.5" or 4.5" diameter. 4" or 5", respectively, is advisable to ensure the pipe passes easily. A rented SDS-MAX rotary hammer can probably manage core drills of this size. It's also possible to hire out the core drilling.
I haven't cored those particular sizes but I've done 2.5" with an SDS-MAX at a speed of 1/2 to 1 inch per minute. I've also cored 8" with a stand-type drill at similar speed. The challenge with SDS-MAX core drills is they're usually not deep enough to penetrate the full depth of the wall. One has to drill an inch or two deep, break out the chunks of concrete, and repeat. I learned that if I get the 2.5" core started, go maybe 1/2" deep, and then run a 1-1/2" twist drill bit all the way through the concrete, and then go back to the core drill, then the concrete usuall breaks away on its own and I don't have to chisel. You might be able to use a stepped approach like this as well.
Once the pipe is inside the house footprint yes it's a matter of cutting out enough floor slab to gain access to the point where the pipe enters the house.

In a nut shell, that's what you'd do. If it's a true slab, foundation, the slab is probably 6" to 8" thick with no footers and is just lying on compacted dirt/gravel. You'd then go through the inside floor until you hit dirt and go under the wall/slab in the direction of the outside drain. The outside pipe will probably be deep, 24 to 30" and you'll need to slope your trench down to where the drain is and make your connection.
